# Java MySQL Hibernate slow select queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, configuration

I have a MySQL table for persistence of some Java objects and use Hibernate for mapping of data/columns. The objects/table contain around 50 columns/fields. On the surface and under minimal load this works fine but I have run into problems on startup of the program where I load all available objects from the table. There is currently around 8500 rows in the table. The loading of these rows takes painfully long, in excess of 5 minutes!. Obviously this isn't right and I must have done something horribly wrong in my Hibernate configuration (or elsewhere). A normal query for all rows using the java.sql.* package takes around 300 ms to retrieve the 8000+ rows which is acceptable, but ideally I would like to keep Hibernate for its mapping functionality.

I have attached the main configuration for Hibernate below. I am happy to provide further configuration/implementation details but I do not want to bloat this question with what may be unnecessary information at this stage.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">

jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/abc</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

  <property name="org.hibernate.SQL">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">250</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>

  <property name= "hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
      org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

I was originally using the default connection pool but tried switching to C3P0 in hope that it would help but the loading time of the rows is basically the same regardless of pool.

Obviously I am anything but a Hibernate expert so I would really appreciate some insight to what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

**UPDATE1**
Adding log output from the queries.

```
20:16:40,633 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:283 - --- HQL AST ---
     \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
        +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
        |  \-[FROM] Node: 'from'
        |     \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
        |        \-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |           +-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |           |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |           |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
        |           |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
        |           |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'xyz'
        |           |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'objects'
        |           |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'abc'
        |           \-[IDENT] Node: 'ObjectID'
        \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
           \-[EQ] Node: '='
              +-[IDENT] Node: 'event_id'
              \-[NUM_INT] Node: '1331570489282'

20:16:40,633 DEBUG QueryTranslatorImpl:252 - --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (order_log)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{derived select clause}'
    |  +-[SELECT_EXPR] SelectExpressionImpl: 'objectid0_.event_id as abc1_0_' {FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=order_log,tableAlias=objectid0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.xyz.objects.abc.objectid}}}
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'objectid0_.order_id as abc2_0_, objectid0_.order_id as order3_0_, objectid0_.px_cond as px4_0_, objectid0_.px_curr as px5_0_, objectid0_.px_value as px6_0_, objectid0_.vol_cond as vol7_0_, objectid0_.vol as vol0_, objectid0_.side as side0_, objectid0_.trd_vol as trd10_0_, objectid0_.open_vol as open11_0_, objectid0_.accno as accno0_, objectid0_.symbol as symbol0_, objectid0_.market as market0_, objectid0_.validity_type as validity15_0_, objectid0_.validity_date as validity16_0_, objectid0_.mod_date as mod17_0_, objectid0_.result_code as result18_0_, objectid0_.order_state as order19_0_, objectid0_.action_state as action20_0_, objectid0_.action_type as action21_0_, objectid0_.action_status as action22_0_, objectid0_.status_text as status23_0_, objectid0_.strategy_id as strategy24_0_, objectid0_.passive as passive0_, objectid0_.timestamp as timestamp0_, objectid0_.confirmedorder as confirm27_0_, objectid0_.updatesource as updates28_0_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[], fromElementByTableAlias=[objectid0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'order_log objectid0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=order_log,tableAlias=objectid0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.abc.objects.xyz.objectid}}
    \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
       \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
          +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'event_id' {originalText=event_id}
          \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '1331570489282'
```

There is a lot more output in the logs but I figured that the 2 items above were the most relevant. If I have missed anything important, please let me know.

**UPDATE2** Adding the actual sql-output.

```
Hibernate: /* from objectid where abc_event_id=1331570505614 */ select objectid0
_.abc_event_id as abc1_0_, objectid0_.abc_order_id as abc2_0_, objectid0_.
order_id as order3_0_, objectid0_.px_cond as px4_0_, objectid0_.px_curr as px5_0_,
 objectid0_.px_value as px6_0_, objectid0_.vol_cond as vol7_0_, objectid0_.vol as v
ol0_, objectid0_.side as side0_, objectid0_.trd_vol as trd10_0_, objectid0_.open_vo
l as open11_0_, objectid0_.accno as accno0_, objectid0_.symbol as symbol0_, ucorde
r0_.market as market0_, objectid0_.validity_type as validity15_0_, objectid0_.vali
dity_date as validity16_0_, objectid0_.mod_date as mod17_0_, objectid0_.result_cod
e as result18_0_, objectid0_.order_state as order19_0_, objectid0_.action_state as
 action20_0_, objectid0_.action_type as action21_0_, objectid0_.action_status as a
ction22_0_, objectid0_.status_text as status23_0_, objectid0_.strategy_id as strat
egy24_0_, objectid0_.passive as passive0_, objectid0_.timestamp as timestamp0_, uc
order0_.confirmedorder as confirm27_0_, objectid0_.updatesource as updates28_0_ f
rom order_log objectid0_ where abc_event_id=1331570505614
```

**UPDATE 3** Object Mapping + Transaction code

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.abc.objects.xyz.objectid" table="order_log">
   <id name="EventId" type="long" column="event_id" >
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>

  <property name="ordId">
    <column name="order_id"/>
  </property>
  <property name="pxCond">
    <column name="px_cond"/>
  </property>
...
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The mapping is an excerpt but it is straight forward along the same lines as above. The Transaction that queries the table looks like below:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
org.hibernate.Transaction transaction = null;
try {
   long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   transaction = session.beginTransaction();
   List<UCOrder> result = session.createQuery("from UCOrder").list();
   transaction.commit();
   System.out.println (result.size() + " rows were retrieved");
   System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t0));
} catch (Exception e) {
   transaction.rollback();
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   session.close();
}
```

Also rather straight forward I would like to think?!?. However, the time it takes to retrieve the data is thousandfold compared to the vanilla `java.sql.*` method illustrated below:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM order_log");
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet ();
```

Comment: Hibernate configuration itself all looks fine.  Could you show the Hibernate code that is actually executing the query? hibernate.show_sql is a good idea also as jabal said.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some log output above.

Comment: The HQL AST is a little too much for me to spot any problems ;) Please just post the relevant SQL queries generated by Hibernate, to log them use `hibernate.show_sql=true` and `hibernate.format_sql=true`.

Comment: @tscho Done. The sql-queries do not appear strange to me.

Comment: The query looks OK, but how many rows does this query retrieve? Can you please also post the hibernate mappings and the code that takes so long to actually load the 8k+ rows.

Comment: @tscho I have posted excerpts of the mapping and the transaction code above in Update 3. I have monitored the query execution on the MySQL server side and it is instantaneous. However, I noticed that there is a long delay (>2 min) from code execution to when the query is fired on the MySQL server so Hibernate (or something else) is doing a lot of thinking before it submits the query to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you switching on a verbose logging in Hibernate. You can get it to log all SQL queries and see if there is something unusual in them.

One way to do this is setting `hibernate.show_sql` to `true` and/or (?) configure commons-logging used by Hibernate to output all `org.hibernate` category to your favourite output file.

Comment: Thanks. I have set the log4j-setting for `org.hibernate=ALL` which gives me a lot of output. Much of it is Greek to me but I have noticed that it specifies all fields (i.e. `SELECT field1, field2,...` rather than selecting with a wildcard (`*`). I don't know if I can change that or if it would make any difference.

Comment: Not really. Resolving (*) to field names is one of the first things that the database does I guess. Hibernate generated SQL is not so nice to read but the answer to the performance issue should hide there.

Comment: Maybe you could copy the queries and analyse them with the MySQL tools to find the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks. I did analyze the queries on the MySQL server with Workbench (see comment above) and the actual query executes in milliseconds. It seems to me like there is some pre and possibly post processing that consumes the time. I do not know what or why though.

Comment: In such cases I usually attach VisualVM (http://visualvm.java.net) to my running program and check where my CPU cycles are spent. This tool can help to find if the bottleneck is in your code or in Hibernate or in network communication.

Comment: Brilliant! It time thief turned out to be logging with log4j. During my testing I have had rather verbose logging for `org.hibernate`. When I change the log level to `INFO` the execution time is down to 1300 ms which is fine. I am very grateful for your help and patience - Thanks.

Comment: Wait, it's OK for a query that takes milliseconds to run to take 1300 milliseconds to be converted into java objects? I realize that is much better than 5 minutes, but you're still dealing with an order of magnitude degradation in performance. I'm having a similar issue with hibernate performing mapping rather slowly, thus the comment. I will try VisualVM to see if it tells me anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't no need transaction in "select".
if you using log4j, please, disable debug for the hibernate.
Apply for association table "mode lazy". This is very important.